# Escaping double quote is not working properly Jdom2

Tags: java, xml, jdom-2

I am writing a parser in Java where I am writing a string in XML dom.
my problem is a String `"test"` should come as `&quot;test&quot;` but it is coming as `"test"`

Here is my code

```
Element elment1 = new Element("string");
elment1.addContent("test");
```

i get it in the xml like this

```
<string>"test"</string>
```

but i want to get it like this

```
<string>&quot;anytext&quot;</string>
```

i use this to creat the xml file

```
Document doc = new Document(root);
XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
xmlOutput.output(doc,new FileWriter("path"))
```

Comment: please check if I got it edited it as intended

Comment: Why? Quoting of "double quotation mark" is needed only in attribute values (and can be avoided by using single quotation marks, and vice versa)

Comment: @forty-two thanks for your answer, i tried to do that with single quotation but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

If you use a standard off-the-shelf serializer, it will not escape a double-quotation-mark `"` appearing in a text node as an entity reference; it will only escape things that actually need to be escaped.

I can't imagine why you would want this unnecessary escaping, but it you do, you will need to do the serialization yourself "by hand".